# Installing Spark with Maven (MAC OSX)

Tags: macos, apache-spark, maven-3

I am very new to Spark and attempting a first time install. I have downloaded homebrew and installed Maven with it.

I have run the following to ensure the install was done correctly:

Command: `maven - v`

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

However, when I try to build spark using the following command:

```
 ./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: ./build/mvn: No such file or directory
```

***UPDATE:***

I went on to follow instructions on instaling Spark with Homebrew from here:

• https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/installing-scala-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-837ae57d283f#.ru5hi42v3
This worked fine untill I restarted the terminal. When I execute

spark-shell
I get :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

Would appreciate any pointers in resolving this.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my .bash_profile to this.

[image]

Still getting the same error. However when I access the files directly by going to the folder via terminal, I can open it.

Comment: Have you added maven to path? 

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin

Comment: I just added it to my .bash_profile using nano. Still the same thing. Does this have anything to do with using hombrew and it been installed in ''cellar''?

Comment: After adding to path, you will still have to source the bash profile, try command ` source ~/.bash_profile`, this will enable you to use mvn anywhere without having to use command like ./build/mvn. You should be in  source code folder for spark where mvn can pick up build.sbt file for building. There is also brew formula available for apache-spark. You can simply try command "brew install apache-spark", and it will do all the work for you..

Comment: Thanks @Pushkr.. I have installed it with homebrew already and appended the source ~/.bash_profile but still getting the error.

Comment: if you have already installed spark using homebrew, then you dont need to build it again. what does the command "spark-submit --version" at terminal yields?

Comment: let me update my answer

Comment: Brew installed spark version 2.1.0 while your path seems to have 2.0.1, add correct path in ~/.bash_profile 
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.1.0/libexec

Comment: @Pushkr I have updated my bash_profile and my question. Still getting the same error

Comment: Can you manually check if the executable file "spark-shell" exists in folder defined by SPARK_HOME/bin? and if it exists, check if you have permission to execute it

Answer (score 1):

If the version of spark you installed is not 2.1.0, then you have to modify the line `export SPARK_HOME= ....` to correspond to version of spark you have.